# R mlogit error : Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level 1

Tags: r, levels, multinomial, mlogit

I have a wide data set that I have converted into long format for estimating in mlogit. In the data I have NO alternative specific data, the values are the same for all alternatives.

```
str(f)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Outcome: logi  FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ X1     : num  0.00437 0.00437 0.00437 0.00437 0.00437 ...
 $ X2     : num  0.00617 0.00617 0.00617 0.00617 0.00617 ...
 $ X3     : num  0.00257 0.00257 0.00257 0.00257 0.00257 ...
 $ chid   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ alt    : chr  "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" ...
```

when I try to estimate a model,

```
model<-mlogit(Outcome~X1+X2+X3,data=f,shape="long",choice="Outcome",alt.var=f$alt)
```

If alt is type char I get this error message:

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level 1

If alt is factor I get this:

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) :    recursive indexing failed
>   at level 2

I have not found any help in regards to these messages in connection with mlogit.

Here is the truncated data I have used (the full data set has 3900 rows). mlogit appears to be very strict about its data. Thanks.

```
structure(list(Outcome = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), X1 = c(0.004373668, 0.004373668, 0.004373668, 0.004373668, 
0.004373668, 0.004373668, 0.00237986, 0.00237986, 0.00237986, 
0.00237986, 0.00237986, 0.00237986, 0.008879354, 0.008879354, 
0.008879354, 0.008879354, 0.008879354, 0.008879354, 0.003356421, 
0.003356421, 0.003356421, 0.003356421, 0.003356421, 0.003356421, 
0.004611897, 0.004611897, 0.004611897, 0.004611897, 0.004611897, 
0.004611897, 0.003225387, 0.003225387, 0.003225387, 0.003225387, 
0.003225387, 0.003225387, 0.003495294, 0.003495294, 0.003495294, 
0.003495294, 0.003495294, 0.003495294, 0.003639481, 0.003639481, 
0.003639481, 0.003639481, 0.003639481, 0.003639481, 0.004911368, 
0.004911368, 0.004911368, 0.004911368, 0.004911368, 0.004911368, 
0.004165713, 0.004165713, 0.004165713, 0.004165713, 0.004165713, 
0.004165713), X2 = c(0.006167994, 0.006167994, 0.006167994, 0.006167994, 
0.006167994, 0.006167994, 0.003977765, 0.003977765, 0.003977765, 
0.003977765, 0.003977765, 0.003977765, 0.004830369, 0.004830369, 
0.004830369, 0.004830369, 0.004830369, 0.004830369, 0.004058219, 
0.004058219, 0.004058219, 0.004058219, 0.004058219, 0.004058219, 
0.004064723, 0.004064723, 0.004064723, 0.004064723, 0.004064723, 
0.004064723, 0.004226818, 0.004226818, 0.004226818, 0.004226818, 
0.004226818, 0.004226818, 0.004199124, 0.004199124, 0.004199124, 
0.004199124, 0.004199124, 0.004199124, 0.004917811, 0.004917811, 
0.004917811, 0.004917811, 0.004917811, 0.004917811, 0.00424221, 
0.00424221, 0.00424221, 0.00424221, 0.00424221, 0.00424221, 0.005516136, 
0.005516136, 0.005516136, 0.005516136, 0.005516136, 0.005516136
), X3 = c(0.002565325, 0.002565325, 0.002565325, 0.002565325, 
0.002565325, 0.002565325, 0.001206929, 0.001206929, 0.001206929, 
0.001206929, 0.001206929, 0.001206929, 0.001917941, 0.001917941, 
0.001917941, 0.001917941, 0.001917941, 0.001917941, 0.001922314, 
0.001922314, 0.001922314, 0.001922314, 0.001922314, 0.001922314, 
0.003243962, 0.003243962, 0.003243962, 0.003243962, 0.003243962, 
0.003243962, 0.001443621, 0.001443621, 0.001443621, 0.001443621, 
0.001443621, 0.001443621, 0.00214728, 0.00214728, 0.00214728, 
0.00214728, 0.00214728, 0.00214728, 0.001188095, 0.001188095, 
0.001188095, 0.001188095, 0.001188095, 0.001188095, 0.002095854, 
0.002095854, 0.002095854, 0.002095854, 0.002095854, 0.002095854, 
0.002529183, 0.002529183, 0.002529183, 0.002529183, 0.002529183, 
0.002529183), chid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), alt = c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L1", 
"L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", 
"L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", 
"L6", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", 
"L5", "L6", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L1", "L2", "L3", 
"L4", "L5", "L6", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6")), .Names = c("Outcome", 
"X1", "X2", "X3", "chid", "alt"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Using the whole dataset, does the command `model <- mlogit(Outcome ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data=f, shape="long", choice="Outcome", alt.var="alt")` yields errors ?

Comment: Yes, that helped me to progress. Thanks. I am now dealing with a singularity issue.

Comment: Check carefully the structure of your dataset. The singularity issue could be generated by one or more variables perfectly correlated to the outcome.

Comment: Yep, I've used this code (from a data mining context) to remove the highly (linearly) correlated variables, Still having issues with p=0.80. But this is another question I fear. PS How do I accept your answer. I can not see a tick to click. `M<-cor(long)])
    highlyCorDescr<-findCorrelation(M, cutoff = .80, verbose = FALSE)
    colnames(long[,highlyCorDescr])
    long_sub<-long[,-highlyCorDescr]`

Comment: I'll look into this. How to measure association between a binary Outcome and an chid integer? For each of the 650 observational unit there are 6 possible outcomes. chid is generated by mlogit.data to 'group' the observations so that the six repetitions of each observational unit have the same chid. The outcome is FALSE for most of the six outcomes, except just one, which is the actual outcome that that observational unit revealed. I can't see why there should be a relationship in my file, with 650x6 rows of long data.

Comment: A simple 2-way table with `Outcome` and `chid` should be able to uncover the relationship between the two variables. Of course I am only making an hypothesis because I have only few elements about your data.

Comment: Of course, thanks for your insight. Just to clarify I found out elsewhere that, since none of my variables vary by outcome I need a model of the form:  `model <- mlogit(Outcome ~ 1 | X1 + X2 + X3, data=f, shape="long", choice="Outcome", alt.var="alt")`